# Problemas con multicell FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Estoy estoy escribiendo un PDF que tengo de plantilla, es una factura.

El problema lo tengo en la descripción del ítem, pues la descripción puede ser una o mas líneas (*por el largo de estas*), el ancho que tengo para descripción son 10 cm.

Para hacer el detalle de la factura recorro el detalle facturas y voy agregando un espaciado de 5 por línea

```
             foreach($ventaDetail as $de){
                //Cantidad siempre es 1
                $pdf->SetXY(5, 105+$espacio); //xy
                $pdf->Write(8, 1);   
                //descripcion puede ser una linea o mas
                $pdf->SetXY(25, 105+$espacio); //xy
                $pdf->MultiCell(120,2+$espacio, $de->descrip_afip,0,'L');
               
                //importe unitario item
                $pdf->SetXY(140, 105+$espacio); //xy
                $pdf->Write(8, number_format($de->subtotal,2,",","."));
                //importe Total
                $pdf->SetXY(175, 105+$espacio); //xy
                $pdf->Write(8, number_format($de->subtotal,2,",","."));
                $espacio=5;
              }
```

y el resultado no es el esperado, si la descripción fuese corta, no habría problemas, el problema es que un item la descripción pueden ocupar tres líneas, la siguiente una, y así.

El resultado que estoy obteniendo es el siguiente:
[image: Imagen actual]

Es primera vez que trabajo con esta librería espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que siempre le estas diciendo que cada "fila" mide `5` y lo que necesitas saber es cuanto es el alto de la caja que genera el `MultiCell`.

Esto lo podes lograr usando `GetY` después de imprimir.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
$pdf->SetXY(5, 105); //xy
foreach ($ventaDetail as $de) {

    $x = $this->GetX();
    $y = $this->GetY();

    // Cantidad (siempre es 1)
    $pdf->Cell(20, 8, '1', false, false);

    // Descripcion (puede ser una linea o mas)
    $xW = $this->GetX();
    $pdf->MultiCell(120, 8, $de->descrip_afip, 0, 'L');
    $yH = $this->GetY(); // Guardamos el alto
    $this->SetXY($xW + 120, $y); // Modificamos las coords

    // Importe unitario
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, number_format($de->subtotal, 2, ",", "."));

    // Importe Total
    $pdf->Cell(35, 8, number_format($de->subtotal, 2, ",", "."));

    //
    $this->SetXY($x, $yH + 2); // Modificamos las coords
}
```

---

También veo que tenes problemas con los acentos y esto se debe a que `FPDF` espera que [el texto este codificado en `windows-1252`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q3)

En la documentación te sugieren esto:

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $str);
```

Otra opción puede ser la siguiente:

```
$str = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str), 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos solo quedo perfecto, solo me queda disminuir espaciado, pues es mucho

Answer (score 2):

**Yo te recomendaría** usar la librería [fpdf-easytable](https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable)

```
<?php
$table = new easyTable($pdf, 4, 'width:100;');

$table->easyCell('CANT.');
$table->easyCell('DESCRIPCION');
$table->easyCell('PRECIO UIT');
$table->easyCell('IMPORTE');
$table->printRow();


$table->rowStyle('min-height:20');
$table->easyCell('Text 1');
$table->easyCell('Text 2');
$table->easyCell('Text 3');
$table->easyCell('Text 4');
$table->printRow();

$table->easyCell('Text 1');
$table->easyCell('Text 2');
$table->easyCell('Text 3');
$table->easyCell('Text 4');
$table->printRow();

$table->endTable();
```

Solamente con eso tendrias tu tabla y ademas se adecua al contenido de los datos como puedes ver en sus ejemplos

[example-2.pdf](https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable/blob/master/example-2.pdf)